# How to share Jenkins BUILD Monitor

Tags: jenkins

We're running a Jenkins build server that is responsible for composing dozens of jobs for our team.  The [Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) is being use to create a dashboard of various builds, and we then project this on a TV in the office; the TV is connected to a dedicated computer (chromebox) that is logged into the Jenkins server and shows the plugin dashboard.

How could I see the dashboard without sitting next to the TV?  Ideally, anyone on the team from anywhere should see the Build Monitor dashboard without logging into the jenkins server (we'd have to share a login).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  The best I can think of is to turn the [chromebox into a remote access point it](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB) remotely, but this feels sloppy.

Comment: Is not possible to just access Jenkins server by its IP address? The same as the TV does.

Comment: Well, the TV is running a chromebox that is logged into a jenkins account.  We could do that, but would have to share a jenkins login which is generally frowned upon at our company (big company/beauracracy)

Comment: That makes sense. Is your server IP public or internal? You can configure Jenkins to make the dashboard Viewable without logging-in. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.  However, the Jenkins server itself is out of our control (managed by another group).  Do you think this can be set at the account level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) to a get finer grain authorization control.

Then you can limit **Anonymous** read access to just the Dashboard view you want to make public. And require authentication for everything else.

In summary, you require:

- A **Project Role** for *anonymous* users
- That **Project Role** will only have *read views* permission for the pattern of the dashboard (`.*view/your-build-monitor-name/`)
- Assing this role to **Anonymous** special user